# pdo all rows does not fetch outside while loop

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to fetch all rows using this below coding. Here you can see `echo $row['UserName'];` and `echo $row['Address'];` i can get all the username and address from database. But when i use this coding (`$uname = $row['UserName'];echo $uname;` and `$uaddress = $row['Address'];echo $uaddress;`) outside of while loop it always fetch the last row values. My question is how to fetch all row values outside of while loop?

```
 <?php
        include('config.php');

        try
        {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM ebusers');
            $conn->errorInfo();
            $stmt->execute();
            while($row = $stmt->fetch()) 
            {   
                echo "<a target=_blank href='edit.php?id=". $row['UserID'] ."'>Edit</a>";
                echo "<br>";
                echo "<a target=_blank href='delete.php?id=". $row['UserID'] ."'>Delete</a>";
                echo $row['UserName'];
                $uname = $row['UserName'];
                echo "<br>";
                echo $row['Address'];
                $uaddress = $row['Address'];
                echo "<br>";
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            'Error : '.$e->getMesssage();
        }

        echo $uname;
        echo $uaddress;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass them into an array

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) 
            {   
                echo "<a target=_blank href='edit.php?id=". $row['UserID'] ."'>Edit</a>";
                echo "<br>";
                echo "<a target=_blank href='delete.php?id=". $row['UserID'] ."'>Delete</a>";
                echo $row['UserName'];
                $uname[] = $row['UserName']; // An array of usernames...
                echo "<br>";
                echo $row['Address'];
                $uaddress[] = $row['Address']; // An another array of addresses
                echo "<br>";
            }

//Below two statements prints all usernames and addresses
print_r($uname); // or you can access like echo $uname[2]  to view the second username
print_r($uaddress); // similarly you can do like that as you did for $uname..

//or if you want to loop through individually , you can make use of a foreach construct
foreach($uname as $usernames)
{
   echo $usernames."<br>";
}
```

Comment: its working. But i'm getting the output like this `Array ( [0] => Administrator [1] => Rahul Dravid )`. How to fetch the details properly like Administartor, Rahul Dravid. When i use echo $uname; i'm getting this following output `Array`

Comment: That's why I gave you a `foreach` construct. Comment the `print_r` statements and give a try.

Comment: Okay. now i got all rows. But this is also using inside the loop. i want to do these things outside of the loop. for example `foreach($uname as $usernames){ $fname = $usernames; } echo $fname;`

Comment: Please ask that in another question.

Answer (score 0):

During the while loop, the `$row` variable get overwritten each time it executed.

You may have a try on [FetchAll](http://www.php.net//pdostatement.fetchall) which prepares the array for you.